# Creating a form in confluence

Tags: confluence

I can create forms via templates with no problem. I found a plugin (create-page) from Adaptavist that allows you to create pages from a template. When a user clicks the create-page macro link it creates/saves the page from the template without allowing the user to change the fields.

I want the create-page macro to allow the user to fill in the form fields before saving the new page.

Is there a way to do this with this macro or perhaps there's another way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [form-mail macro from Adaptavist](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.adaptavist.confluence.formMailNG) was the answer. It allows you to create email forms inside your pages. Mail form NG plugin is free to use up to version 3.03 for Confluence up to version 5.3.4

Answer (score 2):

You can try out [ConfiForms plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.vertuna.confluence.plugins.confiforms) for Confluence. Quite easy to use.